# Show only 1 month old out of stock products

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, inventory, out-of-stock

I'm trying to override the `prepareProductCollection` to show a list of products which will have all in stock products and one month old out of stock products.

So far I was able to filter out the products as I want to but the pagination is not working correctly.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        ...
        // filter product colletion
        foreach ($this->_productCollection as $key => $product ) {

            $date_created       = $product->getCreatedAt();                
            $datetime           = new DateTime($date_created);
            $month_created      = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');

            $current_date       = date("Y-m-d");
            $current_time       = new DateTime($current_date);
            $onemonthbuffer     = $current_time->modify('-3 month')->format('Y-m-d');

            if ( !$product->isSaleable() ){
                 if ( ($month_created < $onemonthbuffer) ) {
                    $this->_productCollection->removeItemByKey($key);
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch using this code.

```
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
$startDate =  Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d 0:0:0', strtotime($date." -30 days"));

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField(
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'product_id=entity_id',
                        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                        'left'
                )
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 0))
                ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $startDate, 'to' => $date));
```

Comment: Nah, this returns me an empty object. I dont want to show only out of stock products btw. I need the whole list (with and without out of stock products), just that the out of stock products should be 1 month old